# “Proceed” vs “proceed with”

Tags: prepositions

Why is right to use this - This will help us proceed with the review of our boss instead of - This will help us proceed the review of our boss?

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct, but have different meanings.

> "Proceed" is a verb means go or continue.

- When you use the word "go" you need to put **`a preposition or adverb(s)`** after it.

---

**Example: Go back, go to, go down, go well, go with, and so on.**

---

- When you use the word "continue" you don't really need to put a preposition or adverb(s) after it, but **`gerund(s) or noun(s)`** instead.

---

**Example: Continue working, continue the story, and so on.**

---

> ***This will help us proceed with the review of our boss.***

This sentence the "proceed" means ***`go`*** because it's followed by a preposition.

*- So the sentence means `you have more than one option, and "this" will help you when you choose to go with "the review of our boss."`*

---

> **This will help us proceed the review of our boss**.

This sentence the "proceed" means ***`continue`*** because it's followed by a noun.

*- So the sentence means `you're working on "the review of our boss", and "this" will help you do it.`